# Creating custom datagenerator in Keras with variable input size

Tags: keras

I am currently working on an image classification problem. Each label that I have is determined from 4 grayscale images of variable size (ranging from 30px to 300px in height and width). Hence, I imagine my input shape to be something like `(None, 4, None, None, 1)`. The first axis will be the batch size, and the third and fourth axis being the height and width respectively.

I am facing difficulty with creating a custom data generator for my use case. I am unable to resize the images as I need to retain the size of certain feature in my images. I understand that padding is a viable solution but it might lead to majority of the image being black pixels due to the large difference of sizes between each set of 4 images. Is there any solution other than padding?

Comment: what do you mean by not able to resize? Did you try extending `Sequence` in keras?

Comment: My work deals with retinal images. And the disease that I am trying to detect makes use of vessels located in the 4 quadrants and one of the symptoms is vessel dilation. Resizing them will lead to different scales. 

Yes, my approach right now is extending the Sequence class. However, I am not sure how to yield X in the required shape.